# BigQuery - equivalent of GROUP EACH in standard SQL

Tags: group-by, google-bigquery

Is there an equivalent of GROUP [EACH](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql) / JOIN EACH in standard SQL ? I'm exceeding my resources.

Comment: Please share the query and an image of the execution plan. There is no equivalent to the `EACH` keyword since you shouldn't need it.

Comment: Is there any query you can run with legacy and EACH and not in standard? please post more details

Comment: @FelipeHoffa my query uses js udf so it's not easily portable to legacy for comparison but since in legacy EACH could be used to solve resource errors I was wondering if that might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. :o(
There is no such equivalent in Standard SQL.
`... EACH` was a hint for BQ Engine (Legacy SQL) to more optimally process respective command  - which is already covered in Standard SQL w/o any hint'ing
Your option is to tune/optimize your query