# Convert Legacy to Standard SQL (Join Each and comma Like)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm struggling to convert this Legacy SQL Query to Standard SQL. Particular things that need to be converted are FLATTEN, JOIN EACH, No matching signature for function REGEXP_REPLACE for argument types: ARRAY, STRING, STRING. Supported signatures: REGEXP_REPLACE(STRING, STRING, STRING); REGEXP_REPLACE(BYTES, BYTES, BYTES), etc. ...Can anyone please help?

Thanks!

```
SELECT a.name, b.name, COUNT(*) as count
FROM (FLATTEN(
SELECT GKGRECORDID, UNIQUE(REGEXP_REPLACE(SPLIT(V2Persons,';'), r',.*'," ")) name
FROM [gdelt-bq:gdeltv2.gkg] 
WHERE DATE>20180901000000 and DATE < 20180910000000 and V2Persons like '%Trump%'
,name)) a
JOIN EACH (
SELECT GKGRECORDID, UNIQUE(REGEXP_REPLACE(SPLIT(V2Persons,';'), r',.*'," ")) name
FROM [gdelt-bq:gdeltv2.gkg] 
WHERE DATE>20180901000000 and DATE < 20180910000000 and V2Persons like '%Trump%'
) b
ON a.GKGRECORDID=b.GKGRECORDID
WHERE a.name<b.name
GROUP EACH BY 1,2
ORDER BY 3 DESC
LIMIT 250
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT a.name, b.b_name, COUNT(*) as count
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT GKGRECORDID, REGEXP_REPLACE(name, r',.*'," ") name
FROM `gdelt-bq.gdeltv2.gkg`, UNNEST(SPLIT(V2Persons,';')) as name
WHERE DATE>20180901000000 and DATE < 20180910000000 and V2Persons like '%Trump%'
) a
JOIN (
SELECT DISTINCT GKGRECORDID, REGEXP_REPLACE(b_name, r',.*'," ") b_name
FROM `gdelt-bq.gdeltv2.gkg`, UNNEST(SPLIT(V2Persons,';')) as b_name 
WHERE DATE>20180901000000 and DATE < 20180910000000 and V2Persons like '%Trump%'
) b
ON a.GKGRECORDID=b.GKGRECORDID
WHERE a.name<b.b_name
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 3 DESC
LIMIT 250
```

Answer (score 1):

Re: the flatten I would consult the documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql#removing_repetition_with_flatten

Among other examples, the documentation notes: 
*"Standard SQL does not have a FLATTEN function as in legacy SQL, but you can achieve similar semantics using the JOIN (comma) operator."*

Re: Join Each, this has been answered here: [BigQuery - equivalent of GROUP EACH in standard SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50769877/bigquery-equivalent-of-group-each-in-standard-sql)

Basically, it is not necessary at all in standard sql

Re: "LIKE that has comma separated parameters...", your syntax is fine for standard sql. it should not operate any differently than it did when you ran in in legacy sql. One of the big pluses of standard sql is that you can compare columns using functions in the WHERE statement with more flexibility than legacy SQL allowed (if necessary). For instance, if you wanted to split V2Persons before running a like comparison, you could do that right in the WHERE statement

UPDATE: Realizing I missed your last question about data type mismatches. In standard sql you will probably want to cast everything explicitly when you run into these errors. It is more finicky than legacy sql with regards to comparisons between different data-types, but I find this to me more in line with other SQL databases.